# What type of DC connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

What type of DC connector is this?

[image: connector]

It's a DC connector and takes 48 VDC. It's from an Ericsson 5G radio (Ericsson 4402 B3 Radio). I am looking to power it straight from a DC bus rather than an AC/DC converter. Approximately 5mm height and 15mm width.

Major Edit: I found the male end, which has some markings on it which may be indicitive of the cable type:

RPM777454/00225 R3A
SIGNAL CABLE T.A
201638 C71-18373172

[image: Cable Image]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: it would really help if the connector is sufficiently lit ... also, there is no way to determine the size of the connector

Comment: What’s the size and pitch?

Comment: Very difficult to measure, but approx. 5mm height and 15mm width. Cannot tell the depth, appending another image which is lit to the main question.

Comment: What does that say on the top of the connector? Is it 202T-02-24?

Comment: @DiBosco 2021-02-24

Comment: Ah, so just a date then.

Comment: @BrandonKellett Is there any more writing on the connector further inside?

Comment: Please tell what type/model of device exactly that is. Sometimes secondary info is vital.

Comment: @AndrewMorton no further writing inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Manufacturer: FCI (now part of Amphenol ICC)
- Manufacturer part number: 10130643-001LF
- Data sheet (drawing): [click](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Amphenol%20PDFs/10130643-1362543.pdf)
- Distributor links (non-stocked): [click](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/amphenol-cs-fci/10130643-001LF/5185748?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIwAY4GYEDYAsyC0CkBkAxEAXQF8g), [click](https://www.mouser.at/ProductDetail/Amphenol-FCI/10130643-001LF?qs=v5m95NEgb1RQyGwyMpIegQ%3D%3D)
- Connector type: Mixed -> signal & power distribution
- Related forum entry: [click](https://forum.digikey.com/t/help-with-male-connector-and-cable-to-10130643-001lf/15567/3)